# reading encoded string HTTP request to android

Tags: android, http

I have a RESTful WCF service that I am using to retrieve encoded photos and display them in android (trying to anyway). The problem I am having is that the InputStream or possibly something else stops reading the characters before the end.

The response is just an XML string, I intend to parse it myself so no need to worry about that. What I need to know is what in the following code is stopping the input stream from reading characters into my buffer.

```
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

char[] buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];
InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
reader.read(buffer);
stream.close();
```

Comment: I dont get an error, "buffer" has a length of nearly 10000, but after about 8200, it is just blank characters

Comment: What u want? u want Encodede data from Http Request?

Comment: no, I have encoded the data. It is retrieved from a HTTP GET request as a string. the char[] 'buffer' contains encoded data, but not all of it. It gets cut off. I need to know why, and how I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the HttpURLConnection class.. this would cause this behavior.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: I have not, are you saying this would cause the behavior I described, or it would fix my problem?